# Why is the Jenks algorithm so slow?

Tags: r, algorithm

I would like to run Jenks' algorithm to find natural breaks in the data. There is a package called classInt that has a function for this, however I need to use it on a machine on which I can't install packages nor compile anything, it has to be done in base R. So I looked at the source and copied the relevant parts to create a jenks() function. 
However the function is egregiously slow! For a single numeric vector of length 300 it takes 0.8 seconds.

I can't figure out why, it's just a few for loops on matrices with pre-allocated memory.The profiler says that most of the time is spent in the '-' function. Is there any way to speed it up?

Thanks!

```
jenks <- function (var, n = 5) {
  ovar <- var

  d <- sort(var)
  k <- n
  mat1 <- matrix(1, length(d), k)
  mat2 <- matrix(0, length(d), k)
  mat2[2:length(d), 1:k] <- .Machine$double.xmax
  v <- 0

  for (l in 2:length(d)) {
    s1 = s2 = w = 0
    for (m in 1:l) {
      i3 <- l - m + 1
      val <- d[i3]
      s2 <- s2 + val * val
      s1 <- s1 + val
      w <- w + 1
      v <- s2 - (s1 * s1)/w
      i4 <- trunc(i3 - 1)
      if (i4 != 0) {
        for (j in 2:k) {
          if (mat2[l, j] >= (v + mat2[i4, j - 1])) {
            mat1[l, j] <- i3
            mat2[l, j] <- v + mat2[i4, j - 1]
          }
        }
      }
    }
    mat1[l, 1] <- 1
    mat2[l, 1] <- v
  }

  kclass <- 1:k
  kclass[k] <- length(d)
  k <- length(d)
  last <- length(d)
  for (j in length(kclass):1) {
    id <- trunc(mat1[k, j]) - 1
    kclass[j - 1] <- id
    k <- id
    last <- k - 1
  }
  brks <- d[c(1, kclass)]


  res <- list(var = ovar, brks = brks)
  res
}
```

Comment: on what function? minus?

Comment: looping is very slow in R, vectorize the algoritm or change the language.

Comment: Yes on the minus function Rawr. Lejlot looping is slow because of memory allocation isn't it? Besides, the following function runs in half the time despite the data being 833 times bigger: x <- matrix(runif(1e6), nrow = 500, ncol = 500); system.time(for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)) x[i] <- x[i+1])

Comment: I profiled your code and although `"-"` indeed shows up as at the top of the summary, only 6% of the total time is spent there. In reality, most of the time must be spent in the `for`, `if`, assignment operators but none of these are recorded or reported it seems.

Comment: You'll get a 4 to 5x speed improvement if you compile this code: `library(compiler); jenks.comp <- cmpfun(jenks)`. Then use `jenks.comp` instead of `jenks`.

Comment: @flodel: `for` and all special primitives are not captured by profiling.

Comment: Its not just "a few for loops". Its a triply-nested for-loop. Which means its efficiency is `O(N^3)` where N is the length of the vector. If your use-case is really 300 elements, then is 0.8s really so much slower than whatever process is generating the 300 elements that it is a problem? If your use-case is >>300 elements then that `O(N^3)` is going to bite you very quickly.